# Understanding dictionary flashcard game errors

Tags: python, dictionary

I have defined a variable (show_definition) and have a dictionary (glossary).

My end goal is to provide the user with a random definition of an unknown word, the user to answer in their head then provide them with an answer after the input of a button.

```
def show_definition():
""" Show the user a random defintion and ask them
    to define it. Show the flashcard
    when the user presses return.    
"""

    random_defin = choice(list(glossary.values()))
    print('Define: ', random_defin)
    input('Press return to see the definition')
    print(glossary.values()[random.defin])
```

The first part works intially choosing a random value from the dictionary however I am completely misunderstanding how to then find the key which correlates to the value getting this error.

TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable.

What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several conceptual issues here, mainly in what `glossary.values()[random.defin]` is doing. You are attempting to find a key in the dict using a value. Dictionaries do not work that way (also you are wrongly trying to use the `values` to do it).

At the moment `glossary` is a dictionary from a word to a definition. Your task will be much easier if you will have a "reversed_glossary" dict from definition to a word:

```
def show_definition():
""" Show the user a random definition and ask them
    to define it. Show the flashcard
    when the user presses return.    
"""

    reversed_glossary = {v: k for k, v in glossary.items()}

    random_defin = choice(list(reversed_glossary.keys()))
    print('Define: ', random_defin)
    input('Press return to see the definition')
    print(reversed_glossary[random_defin])
```

Answer (score -1):

The `.values()` call returns a `dict_values` object, which is *not* the same as a list. If you want to directly index them, you have to make it a list first:

```
print(glossary.values())
print(list(glossary.values()))
print(list(glossary.values())[random_defin])  # fixed random.defin typo
```

Comment: This will produce the error `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Then the `random_defin` is not even an integer yet and wouldn't work to index something with in the first place

Comment: You don't understand what OP is trying to do. `random_defin` is not supposed to be an index. It's a random value from the dictionary